# Retaining delegate until it is used

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks

So I'm writing this API which looks something like this:

```
    @implementation TheApi
    - (ObjectLoaderCallbackDelegate *)createLoaderDelegateForCallback:(ObjectLoaderCallback)callback
    {
        ObjectLoaderCallbackDelegate *loaderDelegate = [[ObjectLoaderCallbackDelegate alloc] init];
        loaderDelegate.didLoadObject = ^(id object) {
            callback(object);
        };
        return loaderDelegate;
    }

    - (void)loadString:(ObjectLoaderCallback)callback
    {
        ObjectLoaderCallbackDelegate *callbackDelegate = [self createLoaderDelegateForCallback:callback];
        ObjectLoader *loader = [[ObjectLoader alloc] init];
        [loader load:@"string" delegate:callbackDelegate];
    }

    - (void)loadNumber:(ObjectLoaderCallback)callback
    {
        ObjectLoaderCallbackDelegate *callbackDelegate = [self createLoaderDelegateForCallback:callback];
        ObjectLoader *loader = [[ObjectLoader alloc] init];
        [loader load:@"number" delegate:callbackDelegate];
    }
    @end
```

When I call [loader load:delegate:], it doesn't keep a strong reference to the delegate (which makes sense).  But because the loader does asynchronous stuff before calling the delegate, the delegate is being released before it ever gets called, resulting in a crashed program.  Here is my solution (which seems a bit dirty):

```
    @interface TheApi : NSObject
    - (void)loadString:(ObjectLoaderCallback)callback;
    - (void)loadNumber:(ObjectLoaderCallback)callback;
    - (void)runCalls;
    @end

    @implementation TheApi
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *loaderDelegates;
        NSMutableSet *callbacksCompleted;
    }

    - (TheApi *) init
    {
        self = [super init];
        if (self != nil) {
            loaderDelegates = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            callbacksCompleted = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
        }
        return self;
    }

    - (void)runCalls
    {
        [loader runLoop];
    }

    - (ObjectLoaderCallbackDelegate *)createLoaderDelegateForCallback:(ObjectLoaderCallback)callback
    {
        NSNumber *delegateRefKey = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:arc4random()];
        ObjectLoaderCallbackDelegate *loaderDelegate = [[ObjectLoaderCallbackDelegate alloc] init];
        loaderDelegate.didLoadObject = ^(id object) {
            callback(object);
            [callbacksCompleted addObject:delegateRefKey];
        };
        [loaderDelegates setObject:loaderDelegate forKey:delegateRefKey];
        return loaderDelegate;
    }

    - (void)removeCompletedDelegates
    {
        // So we can remove items from callbacksCompleted in the loop...
        NSMutableSet *callbacksCompletedIterSet = [callbacksCompleted copy];

        // Remove old delegates for calls already completed which are stored
        for (id key in callbacksCompletedIterSet) {
            [loaderDelegates removeObjectForKey:key];
            [callbacksCompleted removeObject:key];
        }
    }

    - (void)loadString:(ObjectLoaderCallback)callback
    {
        [self removeCompletedDelegates];
        ObjectLoaderCallbackDelegate *callbackDelegate = [self createLoaderDelegateForCallback:callback];
        ObjectLoader *loader = [[ObjectLoader alloc] init];
        [loader load:@"string" delegate:callbackDelegate];
    }

    - (void)loadNumber:(ObjectLoaderCallback)callback
    {
        [self removeCompletedDelegates];
        ObjectLoaderCallbackDelegate *callbackDelegate = [self createLoaderDelegateForCallback:callback];
        ObjectLoader *loader = [[ObjectLoader alloc] init];
        [loader load:@"number" delegate:callbackDelegate];
    }
    @end
```

So here, I'm keeping a reference to the delegates in an instance-level dictionary where they key is unique for each API method call.

So my question is: is there a better way to do keep the delegates from being released and then freeing them after the loader calls them?

Comment: Why does it not make sense for the loader to retain its delegate? If it depends on that object it should retain it until it's finished with it.

Answer (score 0):

I recently asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17348523/423565) and learnt about 'associated objects'.  It seems like this may solve your issue.

@CRD provides a good explanation in his answer - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/17351118/423565