# Why delegate references are weak?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I have two UIViewControllers in a UINavigationController.
viewControllerA is the delegate of viewControllerB.
Obviously, viewControllerA doesn't have a reference to viewControllerB.
viewControllerB has a reference to viewControllerA because vcA is the delegate of vcB.

**I've been told that delegates references should be weak.**
In my case, I don't think it's true.
If the UINavigationController will decide to let go of vcA, vcB's delegate would be nil.
But, if the reference to vcA was strong, vcB would still have a reference to it.

Then why delegates are weak?
Yes, I know it's been asked before. Yes, I've spent time trying to understand this.
Yet I don't seem to understand any of this.

Thank you.

Comment: Because if an object X sets itself as the delegate of object Y, then very probably X has a strong ref to Y, and if Y had one to X (its delegate) too, that would cause a retain cycle.

Comment: I assume that vcA is the `rootViewController` and that vcB is pushed on top of that?

Comment: @meaning-matters Exactly.

Comment: Read [Is it ever Ok to have a 'strong' reference for a delegate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348523/is-it-ever-ok-to-have-a-strong-reference-for-a-delegate), a recent question on this topic which should explain the issue for you.

Comment: because the retain cycle can be broken at point to avoid memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, delegates should be weak (or assign in non-ARC code) to avoid cycles.

A typical case, that we see in many samples, is:

```
_myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
_myViewController.delegate = self;
```

This produces a cycle if the delegate is strong, because _myViewController is referenced by the original object, which in turn is referenced by _myViewController.

Comment: You can remove `In my opinion` from your answer, that's the only reason why delegates should be `weak/assign`. ;))

Comment: There can also be good reasons for a strong reference to a delegate, see `NSURLConnection`.

Comment: @MartinR: Although they are both called "delegates," it seems to me that the temporarily retained object an NSURLConnection needs to get actual work done during its short lifetime is a somewhat different thing than, say, a view controller's delegate.

Comment: @Chuck: Yes. I only said this because both the question and the answers quite generally state *"delegate references should be weak"*.

Answer (score 0):

I think when Class B is providing a delegate to Class A. Class A will assign a strong delegate to this delegate, now if Class B also makes this delegate Strong, this will result in Memory leak. As both class hold a strong reference to this delegate, it can't be released till some makes it weak and other one goes out of memory.

[Good Link](http://dannysu.com/2012/07/30/automatic-reference-counting-on-ios/)