# Delegate that's alive until the final method is invoked, but under ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

In my non-ARC iOS code, I use the following pattern: a delegate proxy class that forwards a single delegate message to some other class, then releases self. Here's an example for UIAlertView:

```
@interface AlertCallback : NSObject
<UIAlertViewDelegate>
{
    NSObject *m_Sink;
    SEL m_SinkSel;
}

-(id)initWithSink:(id)Sink SinkSel:(SEL)Sel;
@end

@implementation AlertCallback

-(id)initWithSink:(id)Sink SinkSel:(SEL)Sel
{
    if(self = [super init])
    {
        m_Sink = Sink;
        m_SinkSel = Sel;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)av didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)n
{
    //Call the callback
    [m_Sink performSelector:m_SinkSel withObject:@(n)];
    [self autorelease];
}

@end


//And finally usage:
AlertCallback *del =
    [[AlertCallback alloc]
        initWithSink:self
        SinkSel:@selector(OnIAmSure:)];
UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil
    message:@"Are you sure?"
    delegate: del
    cancelButtonTitle:@"No"
    otherButtonTitles: @"Yes", nil];
```

The idea here is that the proxy object will stay alive until the user taps a button, at which point the proxy will invoke its host's method and commit suicide. I'm using a similar pattern for action sheet and connections.

This doesn't translate to ARC. The delegate on the UIAlertView is weak. With only a weak ref to it, the AlertCallback with be released right away.

I can see several ways to overcome this. The callback can hold a reference to self (a deliberate ref loop) and nil it when the delegate message comes. It's also possible to derive a class from UIAlertView, implement the delegate protocol, and make it designate self as the delegate - but overriding the init method would be tricky; I don't know how to override a variadic method, passing an unknown number of parameters to the superclass. Finally, I could build a category on top of UIAlertView, specifying self as delegate, and use `objc_setAssociatedObject` for extra data items. Clunky, but it might work.

Is there a preferred/recommended way to implement this pattern under ARC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first solution, keeping a self reference, works fine - see for example [Manual object lifetime with ARC](http://PR%C3%89PAREZ%20VOTRE%20ARRIV%C3%89E%20Avant%20votre%20arriv%C3%A9e%20sur%20place%20le%2021/09/2015,%20pensez%20%C3%A0%20contacter%20le%20propri%C3%A9taire%20de%20l'h%C3%A9bergement%20pour%20convenir%20de%20votre%20heure%20d'arriv%C3%A9e.).

If you cannot, or do not wish to, modify the class to manage its own lifetime then a standard solution is to use *associated objects*. This is a standard runtime feature which effectively allows the lifetime of one object to be linked to that of another. In your case you can associate your delegate to your `UIAlertView`, effectively making the delegate reference strong rather than weak. Many questions on SO deal with associated objects, for example see [Is it ever OK to have a 'strong' reference to a delegate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348523/is-it-ever-ok-to-have-a-strong-reference-for-a-delegate/17351118#17351118).

HTH