# weakSelf & Delegate

Tags: ios, memory-management, delegates

As we know, we will declare a delegate object with weak that can break strong reference cycle:

```
// MyObject.h

...

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<MyDelegate> delegate;

...

// ViewController.m

...

 self.myObject.delegate = self;

...
```

and I want to know: can we declare delegate with strong, and set a weakSelf to it:

```
// MyObject.h

...

@property (nonatomic, strong) id<MyDelegate> delegate;

...

// ViewController.m

...

__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
self.myObject.delegate = weakSelf;

...
```

Comment: you _could_ but you are supposed not to create potential strong reference cycles deliberately; it seems logically the `weakSelf` immediately has got a `strong` reference when you assigned it to your `strong` property.

Comment: Does it will cause reference cycle?

Comment: as long as you are having a `strong` pointer, you _could_ create a strong-reference cycle in that case.

Answer (score 1):

A delegate is a common design pattern used in Cocoa and CocoaTouch frameworks, where one class delegates responsibility for implementing some functionality to another. This follows a principle of separation of concerns, where the framework class implements generic functionality while a separate delegate instance implements the specific use case.

Delegate properties being weak is a recommendation to help avoid retain cycles.For explaination check @Bary Walk ans [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449040/why-use-weak-pointer-for-delegation). However, there are use cases where a strong reference is preferred, or even necessary. Apple uses this in NSURLConnection: An NSURLConnection instance can only be used once. After it finishes (either with failure or success), it releases the delegate, and since the delegate is readonly, it can't be (safely) reused.Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348523/is-it-ever-ok-to-have-a-strong-reference-for-a-delegate) previous SO ques for reference.

Answer (score 0):

As far as my knowledge declaring a object weak it means you are not own that object, so assigning strong delegate to it won't work.